# Synchronize HTML5 audio and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, html5-audio

I am writing a simple game by JavaScript, in which sound should be parallel with JavaScript.

I am using `setInterval` and I should be sure if the sound is playing correct, without pauses and delays.

I think about it this way: user can start game, when audio is loaded.

How can I do it? Maybe you can advise me another way.

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at JPlayer, you could load the audio track:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
ready: function () {
$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
mp3: "track.mp3"
});
}
});
```

And then when your game is ready to start playing call:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play", 0);
```

or if you want to check if the audio is playing:

```
if(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime > 0) { 
    //Game start
}
```